# Trouble sending a specific request with null parameters to an API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, http-get

This is an example of the controller I've built in .Net Core 2.1.

```
[Route("api/TestApi")]
public class TestApiController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{param1?}/{param2?}/{param3?}")]
    //[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(int? param1 = null, DateTime? param2 = null, bool? param3 = null)
    {
       //Get data ...
    }
}
```

My issue with this set up is that I cannot call this function with a null parameter;
This kind of call will not work: http://localhost:9000/api/TestApi/null/null/true. It will give me an error stating that null is not a valid input for param1.

Now I cannot rely on reading parameters from a query string (company constraints)
but I would like to point out that it does work if I use [HttpGet] instead and use the url parameters.

Any ideas? suggestions? questions? 
All would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't your url be http://localhost:9000/api/TestApi/null/null/true ?

Comment: Optional (nullable) action method parameters should be in the query string.  Why does your company have such constraints?

Comment: Fixed the url. This scenario does work if I use query string.. just got the example wrong. @Brad I don't know, that's not the right question to ask, is it impossible to place null parameters this way then?

Comment: There's no need to name the params in [HttpGet] when they are optional.  MVC will populate them from the query string if they exist, otherwise they'll be null.  It may not be the right question for me to ask you, granted, but it may be worth you asking the company.

Comment: Well. I asked already and I understood they've already begun developing this way for the past couple of days. the important question to ask is, do I have to use query string input to be able to use null parameters?

Comment: It depends on the type of parameter.  I only use route (path) parameters for the purpose of resource identification (id's, names, keys etc.).  Any parameters that are optional or nullable I put in the query string.  This is usually obvious because more often than not these are variables that are used for querying data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found sort of a patch to use.

It involves adding a middle ware in Startup.cs file.

```
  services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = false;
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
            {
                if (
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(actionContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template)
                && actionContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template.Contains("?"))
                {
                    //Hard coded removed bad error if template has int?/double?/datetime?
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    var errors = actionContext.ModelState
                       .Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                       .Select(e => new Error
                       {
                           Name = e.Key,
                           Message = e.Value.Errors.First().ErrorMessage
                       }).ToArray();

                    return new BadRequestObjectResult(errors);
                }
            };
        });
```

I have managed to finally use the URL I specified in the question;
http://localhost:9000/api/TestApi/null/null/true

Again, it's not a solid solution, just a workaround.